# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: drupal-7

I am getting below error in drupal 7

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '))' at line 2:
>   SELECT t__0.* FROM {file_display} t__0 WHERE
>   (name IN ()) ; Array ( ) in ctools_export_load_object()

anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending empty ids list "WHERE (name IN ())".

You have to check and use not empty ids array or add checking of the ids array on empty condition